# Wondering what the phrase "down close" mean in an economic-related context?

Tags: word-meaning

Down close to 5 percents.
It was talking about market and shares.

Comment: For example? ["The stock is down close to 5 percent on the Hong Kong Exchange"](http://www.rttnews.com/2268950/prada-annual-sales-growth-reflects-weak-europe-stock-down.aspx).

Answer (score 1):

“5 percent**s**”, with *percent* in the plural, is very unlikely here. It ***can*** mean “bonds paying five percent interest”, but in that case the phrase *down close to 5 percents* would not be meaningful.

I think it probable that what is meant is “5 percent”, with *percent* in the singular.

For something to *be **down*** in market language means that its price has decreased. It is very common to say that a price is *down AMOUNT* as a shorthand way of saying that its price has decreased ***by AMOUNT***.

- If what you read is that *X is down close to 5%* (or *5 percent*), ***close*** is a component of the phrasal adverb *close to* = “near”; it is pronounced with /s/.

  This means that the price of X has decreased by nearly 5%.
- If what you read is that *X closed down 5%*, ***close*** is a verb meaning “have a price at the close of trade, at the end of the trading day”; it is pronounced with /z/.

  This means that at the point in time when the market closed for the day, the price of X had decreased by 5%.

*Close* may also be used as a noun, pronounced with a /z/ and meaning “the close of trade, the end of the trading day”: *X was down 5% at (the) close*.